# Fetch the Value of Key from json when If condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON with following structure

```
                   [
                          {"key":1,"name":"aaa"},
                          {"key":2,"name":"bbb"}

               ]
```

i need to get the object whose key is 2 and i have to make it as separate array like

```
                         [

                          {"key":2,"name":"bbb"}

                         ]
```

for instance i have given just 2 objects it can be more than 100 . Can someone help me to implement this in efficient way

Comment: `.filter()` if you have multiple objects with `key` property as `1` and you want to get all of them however `.find()` if you want to get the first occurrence of the subject object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#find` might be helpful.

```
let obj = arr.find(v => v.key == 2);
```

If you want to store it inside an array:

```
let obj = [arr.find(v => v.key == 2)];
```

Or a loop approach (when condition is met - break the loop):

```js
let arr = [{
    "key": 1,
    "name": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "name": "bbb"
  }
];

let res = [];

for (let elem of arr) {
  if (elem.key == 2) {
    res.push(elem);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`:

```
var result = data.filter(function(val){
   return val.key==2;
});
```

I hope be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is this method is efficient than array.find() . I mean which is better when we have more than 100 objects

Comment: I dont know if there are any benckmark for this! `filter` runs till the end of the array, and invokes its callback on every item; in contrast to `find` which stops after having found one. When the callback throws an exception on one of these additionally iterated elements, the outcome is different.